# Current menu item customization not working

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, menuitem

I got 2 current items on my web-site, the second is a section from home but i need to highlight only the first one, how can i do that? i added a class to the second menu item and tried to modify but it doesnt work. noob wordpress designer here. the site: https://www.crescentbun.testebossnet.ro/ any help would be apreciate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The class does not seem to be added. So the CSS won't apply

Comment: but edits like font-size works...

Comment: __The class is not added__ Do you see it anywhere in your html ? Because I don't

Comment: srry mate, i added it again now, i tought it has nonsense if it doesnt work and deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class set is canceled because there is css from the theme overwriting it like:

```
.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #f4ab02!important;
}
```

And as you tried to set the CSS on `li` and there is a CSS applied on your `a` under the `li` the CSS is canceled.

So set your CSS like:

```
.aboutus span{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you for spending your time explaining, i got it:D have a nice life man